# How do I install a python package

Tags: python, linux, installation, package

I want to install this python package:
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/netifaces/0.5

But I don't know how and I know nothing about python. Still, I guess there is a standardized way to install it. Am I right?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check easy_install : http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/EasyInstall#using-easy-install

Comment: It may be time to start recommending http://packages.python.org/distribute/ instead of setuptools.  Download and run http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py instead, then pretend you just installed setuptools and carry on...  (From what I can tell, setuptools is dead, distribute is a now-temporary replacement that's actually supported, and the future is evolving even as I write...)

Answer (score 2):

From http://pypi.python.org/pypi:

> to use a package from this index
>   either "pip install package" or
>   download, unpack and "python setup.py
>   install" it.

That said, often distributions of Linux package a lot in their repositories, so try those too.

Comment: I tried searching on apt before. Still, I don't know whether pip is a bash command or a python shell command. I tried both and failed. Could you please point me out how do I execute this command/install something to execute it?

Answer (score 0):

You can download the binary for windows from here or use easy_install as the above poster said
http://alastairs-place.net/2007/03/netifaces/netifaces-0.4-py2.4-win32.egg